# How can I use my twilio trunk for ONLY outbound calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

My twilio phone number is set to call forward (with a twiml bin) to my physical phone.  This works perfectly and I do not want inbound calls to involve a SIP trunk, etc.

However, when I place an outbound call from my voip dialer, I want to place it from my twilio number so I am setting up a SIP trunk for that.

It seems to be straightforward but it has never worked ...

- I name the trunk
- I set the termination SIP URI (mytrunkname).sip.twilio.com
- I created and set a credential with username/password
- I did NOT add a IP ACL since I don't want one
- I set nothing in the "origination" section
- I did NOT add any numbers to the SIP trunk - since I don't want inbound calls to go to the trunk - I want inbound calls to keep using my call-forwarding twiml bin

Then I use the SIP URI and the user/pass in my VOIP dialer ... and it always fails.  It cannot auth/connect properly to my trunk.

What am I missing here ?  Is it impossible to only use a SIP trunk for outbound calling and I *need* to configure the number in the SIP trunk and give up my call forward twiml bin ?

Thanks.

Comment: It was wrong of me to use a SIP trunk for this.  I have this working properly now with no SIP trunk - I just used "programmable voice" and set up a SIP domain, then added a single credential to it and then enabled SIP registration (and added that same credential list to SIP registration).  Then I put this into my softphone (in my case, groundwire) and it works - outbound calls from groundwire appear to come from my twilio number.  The last piece is to make a simple twiml bin and set that twiml bin URL as the "request URL" for the SIP domain.

Answer (score 0):

The twiml bin that you need to add to the SIP domain looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+14159997777">{{#e164}}{{To}}{{/e164}}</Dial>
</Response>
```

(when you create a twiml bin, twilio creates a unique URL for that twiml bin and you can put that URL into the "request URL" input for the SIP domain.

It appears that at this time, you cannot define human readable caller ID (names, etc.) for twilio provisioned numbers, so your caller ID is just going to be a number ...

... which is totally lame.  Twilio, fix this please.